# How to grant privileges on specific table with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, roles

I want to grant some privilege to role in specific table.
Here is what I try

```sql
CREATE ROLE EDITOR WITH PASSWORD 'EDITOR';
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO EDITOR;
GRANT INSERT ON ALL COMMENTARY IN SCHEMA public TO EDITOR;
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL ARTICLES IN SCHEMA public TO EDITOR;
```

But I have syntax error at near "COMMENTARY IN" I think I miss something but I don't know what.

Comment: There is no such thing as "ALL COMMENTARY IN".  Did something lead you to believe there was?  There are database objects known as comments, but they have no grantable permissions attached to them.  Did you just mean a table named "commentary"?  In that case, it would be `ON public.commentary TO`

Answer (score 0):

There is no "commentary" object in PostgreSQL and there is also no object "article".

If these objects are types you have created, you should use the right syntax:

```
GRANT { USAGE | ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
    ON TYPE type_name [, ...]
    TO role_specification [, ...] [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
```

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-grant.html.